# Serialize error for a class not present in class being serialized

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to serialize data but a strange error occurs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=There was an error generating the XML document.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o)
   at Starbreaker.Form1.Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Doven\source\repos\Starbreaker\Starbreaker\Form1.cs:line 322
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: You must implement a default accessor on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject because it inherits from ICollection.
```

The way I'm trying to serialize the data:

```cs
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(setting));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(new FileStream(settings.Xml, FileMode.Create), settings);
    xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Station>));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(new FileStream(settings.StationsXml, FileMode.Create), settings.Stations);
    xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Systems>));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(new FileStream(settings.SystemsXml, FileMode.Create), settings.Systems); // error thrown here
}
```

Both of the `Stations` and `Systems` classes don't have any `JObjects` yet the error cites that I need a default accessor. I do use `JObjects` but not in those classes or even in the `settings` class except a JSON deserializer. Another strange thing that happens is the file suddenly cuts off at the same place each time:

```xml
...
          <Active_States>
            <id>80</id>
            <name>None</name>
          </Active_States>
        </active_states>
        <pending_states />
        <recovering_states />
      </Minor_Faction_Presences>
      <Minor_Faction_Presences>
        <happiness_id>2</happiness_id>
        <minor_faction_id>42317</minor_faction_id>
        <influence>12.249</influence>
        <active_states>
          <Active_States>
            <id>73</id>
            <name>War</name>
          </Active_States>
        </active_states>
        <pending_states />
        <recovering_states />
      </Minor_Faction_Presences>
    </minor_faction_presences>
    <ed_system_address>2656194005347</ed_system_address>
  </Systems>
  <Systems>
    <id>4</id>
    <edsm_id>19210</edsm_i[eof]
```

The first three objects seem to sterilize fine but it fails at the beginning of the fourth. Here are the two classes and subclasses: [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/Fyue8qWP)

Comment: Are you sure? What are `settings.Stations` and `settings.Systems`? Post the code `Form1_FormClosing` *and* the definitions of those objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The classes are 200+ lines of code so I made it into a Pastebin.

Comment: Nobody is going to read it there. Post the relevant parts. Somehow, somewhere, a JObject *is* used

Comment: More importantly, post the code that throws - the `Form1_Closing` event handler, specifically line 322. Are you serializing the wrong object perhaps?

Comment: You have `object` in `Minor_Faction_Presences` - any chance it is that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Line 322 *is* the line marked with `// error thrown here` and to prove that the JObject isn't referenced in the class I need to show the entire class. Click on the pastebin link and use `Ctrl`+`F` and type in `jobject`. It will come up with 0 results.

Comment: @DoshorteDovencio there's no such line in the code, at least no *visible* line. If you want help, you have to post something that actually demonstrates *and reproduces the problem*. You still haven't posted what `settings.SystemsXML` is or how it's assigned. The one thing that's *certain* is that one of those properties contains a `JObject`.

Comment: @DoshorteDovencio btw as Marc said, there's an `object` property in the code. This could contain anything. I tried to read that pastebin and missed that among the unrelated enums. You should post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself. Something people can use to actually reproduce the error. Quite often, doing this helps you solve the bug as well, as you isolate and concentrate on the relevant parts of the code

Comment: In fact, a very common troubleshooting trick is to create a new console project with only enough code to reproduce a problem.

Comment: @MarcGravell Fixed it thanks for the help if you make it an answer I'll accept it. The objects just needed to be defined as classes `object` -> `Pending_states` or `Recovering_States`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you asked for the code. Please handle it in a professional way when someone does what you ask, but doesn't do what you want. That is programming and you ought to know that. This problem is a great example of that. The program gave me and the XML serializer something I or the serializer didn't expect. Besides if you were getting lost in something that's irrelevant you just skip past that or ask me to remove it instead of complaining that it's long. You also asked for irrelevant information yourself when you asked for the whole `Form1_FormClosing` function. It was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model contains:

```cs
        public object[] pending_states { get; set; }
        public object[] recovering_states { get; set; }
```

Since those are the only non-obvious types in the data, I'm guessing that one (or both) of these is the culprit, containing some `JObject` data. Presumably: replace them with things that... *don't*.